# Unable to retrieve a high quality image from google drive API

Tags: cors, aws-lambda, google-drive-realtime-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

Im trying to launch an application with a serverless architecture using AWS Lambda and a React frontend. The Lambda function works fine and is currently retrieving the data from my google drive. Unfortunately, The main purpose of this data is to serve images on my site, and the only working Image option the google data provides is a thumbnail link. Naturally this gets pixelated when scaling to the size I'm using. Here is a snippet of the data I'm choosing to retrieve from what is brought back by the google API call.

```
          let filteredResults = res.data.items.map( (el) => {
              return {
                        "title": el.title,
                        "description": el.description,
                        "id": el.id,
                        "embedLink": el.embedLink,
                        "thumbnailLink": el.thumbnailLink,
                        "createdDate": el.createdDate,
                        "modifiedDate": el.modifiedDate,
                     }
          });
```

As for what is available to choose from, the list is quite extensive and I won't post it all here. Here's a snippet of what appears to be what I have to work with

```
id: '',
    etag: '',
    selfLink: '',
    webContentLink: '',
    alternateLink: '',
    embedLink: '',
    iconLink: ''.
    thumbnailLink: '',
```

The images are being displayed on the frontend using a component like so

```
<MarinerImage src={props.driveData[0].thumbnailLink}>
</MarinerImage>
```

If I use any of the other available link types, this is the result 
'Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response'

So once again, I'm just wondering if there's something I'm not seeing in the response data that could be used to generate a higher quality image. Failing that, Is there any way to configure things directly from my drive so that I could response to an API call with a higher quality image? It seems odd that I can't get anything other than a thumbnail. Thanks very much for any effort or time invested in this.

Comment: I resolved this issue. It turned out WebContentLink was the way to go. I was so sure that resulted in a CORB before, but it seems to be working